# C read csv file put struct array with int variable error"strcpy"-

Tags: c, csv, strcpy

I need to read a `.csv` file. Then I need to put on "value" struct array, but when I put integer variable I'm getting this `"expected ‘char * restrict’ but argument is of type ‘int’" error`.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define DATA_FILE "students.csv"
typedef struct record {
 int id;
 int grade;
char name[15];
char surname[15];
char email[26];

 }dict;

int main()
 {

FILE *fp;
struct record Myrecord;
fp=fopen("students.csv","r");
 if(!fp){
   printf("Error occured");
   return 0;

 }
 char buff[102400];
 int row_count=0;
 int field_count=0;
 dict values[99900];
 int i=0;
 while(fgets(buff,102400,fp))
 {
  field_count=0;
  row_count++;
  if(row_count == 1){
    continue;
  }
 
  
  char *field=strtok(buff,";");
  
  while (field)
  {
   if(field_count==0){
        
         strcpy(values[i].id,field);
    }
    if(field_count==1){
    strcpy(values[i].name,field);
    }
    if(field_count==2){
    strcpy(values[i].surname,field);
    }
    if(field_count==3){
    strcpy(values[i].email,field);
    }
    if(field_count==4){
    strcpy(values[i].grade,field);

    }
    printf("%s  ",field);
    field=strtok(NULL,";");
    field_count++;

  }    
  i++;
  
  
}   



return 0;
}
```

This is a sample csv file:

[image]

This is the error I am getting:

```
week3.c: In function ‘main’:
week3.c:44:30: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘strcpy’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
              strcpy(values[i].id,field);
                     ~~~~~~~~~^~~
In file included from week3.c:2:
/usr/include/string.h:121:14: note: expected ‘char * restrict’ but argument is of type ‘int’
 extern char *strcpy (char *__restrict __dest, const char *__restrict __src)
              ^~~~~~
week3.c:56:18: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘strcpy’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
  strcpy(values[i].grade,field);
         ~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~
In file included from week3.c:2:
/usr/include/string.h:121:14: note: expected ‘char * restrict’ but argument is of type ‘int’
 extern char *strcpy (char *__restrict __dest, const char *__restrict __src)
              ^~~~~~
Segmentation fault

[Done] exited with code=139 in 0.174 seconds
```

Comment: That repeated `if(field_count==0) ...` construct.  Don't do that.  Use a `switch`.  If you want others to look at your code, it is _polite_ to make it readable and indent conventionally and place braces consistently.  Most dedicated code editors will form at your code for you.

Comment: That "csv line" is no csv line. It is multiple lines and is not comma separated. Also no `;` as your program seems to expect. Instead of a picture of some program that displays, please copy exact content into your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> week3.c:44:30: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘strcpy’ makes
> pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
>               strcpy(values[i].id,field);
>                      ~~~~~~~~~^~~
> ```

id is an integer, field is a string - you cannot copy a string to an integer - you have to _interpret _ the string:

```
values[i].id = (int)strtol( field, NULL, 0 ) ;
```

Although quite possibly the `id` should be a string in any case, even if it contains only digits - it is not an object you are going to perform arithmetic on after all.

> ```
> In file included from week3.c:2: /usr/include/string.h:121:14: note:
> expected ‘char * restrict’ but argument is of type ‘int’  extern char
> *strcpy (char *__restrict __dest, const char *__restrict __src)
>               ^~~~~~
> ```

Is simply a consequence of the previous error.  Always read and fix errors from the top, and recompile if the message looks like a "run-on" from a previous issue.

> ```
> week3.c:56:18: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘strcpy’ makes pointer
> from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]  
> strcpy(values[i].grade,field);
>          ~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~ In file included from week3.c:2: /usr/include/string.h:121:14: note: expected ‘char * restrict’ but
> argument is of type ‘int’  extern char *strcpy (char *__restrict
> __dest, const char *__restrict __src)
>               ^~~~~~
> ```

Same as above.

```
values[i].grade = (int)strtol( field, NULL, 0 ) ;
```

Though clearly here, `grade` being an integer makes sense.

> ```
> Segmentation fault
> ```

You ran the broken code because they were warnings not errors.  All compilers have switches to regard warnings as errors (a warning is normally a semantic error rather then a syntactic error - that is the compiler can generated code, but it is unlikely that the code means what you intended), you should use that switch (`-Werror` in GCC and Clang, `\WX` in Microsoft's compiler).  Code with errors won't run because it won't compile - so making warnings into errors prevents you from running semantically broken code.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the error message. `strcpy` takes two `char *` arguments, but in `strcpy(values[i].id,field)`, `values[i].id` is `int`.

The prototype of `strcpy` is included in the compiler output:

```
extern char *strcpy (char *__restrict __dest, const char *__restrict __src)
```